# Customer emails not sending any more in Magento 1.9.3.2 via cronjob

Tags: magento

Magento customer e-mails are not sending any more after update. It shows following message in the cron_schedule table. Our hoster is mittwald and they use a special cron.sh which not uses "ps".

```
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE (message_id='33')' at line 1' in /html/update_1.9.3/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /html/update_1.9.3/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /html/update_1.9.3/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /html/update_1.9.3/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /html/update_1.9.3/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /html/update_1.9.3/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('UPDATE `v1_core...', Array)
#5 /html/update_1.9.3/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('UPDATE `v1_core...', Array)
#6 /html/update_1.9.3/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(635): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('UPDATE `v1_core...', Array)
#7 /html/update_1.9.3/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(433): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->update('v1_core_email_q...', Array, 'message_id='33'')
#8 /html/update_1.9.3/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue))
#9 /html/update_1.9.3/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Queue.php(246): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#10 [internal function]: Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue->send(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule))
#11 /html/update_1.9.3/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(326): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#12 /html/update_1.9.3/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(72): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->_processJob(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#13 /html/update_1.9.3/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1358): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->dispatch(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#14 /html/update_1.9.3/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1337): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Observer), 'dispatch', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#15 /html/update_1.9.3/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('default', Array)
#16 /html/update_1.9.3/cron.php(78): Mage::dispatchEvent('default')
#17 {main}

Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE (message_id='33')' at line 1, query was: UPDATE `v1_core_email_queue` SET  WHERE (message_id='33')' in /html/update_1.9.3/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235
Stack trace:
#0 /html/update_1.9.3/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /html/update_1.9.3/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /html/update_1.9.3/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /html/update_1.9.3/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('UPDATE `v1_core...', Array)
#4 /html/update_1.9.3/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('UPDATE `v1_core...', Array)
#5 /html/update_1.9.3/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(635): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('UPDATE `v1_core...', Array)
#6 /html/update_1.9.3/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(433): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->update('v1_core_email_q...', Array, 'message_id='33'')
#7 /html/update_1.9.3/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue))
#8 /html/update_1.9.3/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Queue.php(246): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#9 [internal function]: Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue->send(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule))
#10 /html/update_1.9.3/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(326): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#11 /html/update_1.9.3/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(72): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->_processJob(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#12 /html/update_1.9.3/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1358): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->dispatch(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#13 /html/update_1.9.3/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1337): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Observer), 'dispatch', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#14 /html/update_1.9.3/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('default', Array)
#15 /html/update_1.9.3/cron.php(78): Mage::dispatchEvent('default')
#16 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

There was an error in v1_core_email_queue WHERE (message_id='33').

The order with the id 33 was already deleted. The solution was just to delete the entry with the id 33.

Comment: Obviously the error is generated by the mPAY24 payment extension when the payment process is terminated.

Comment: There is no problem with the mPAY24 extension and to delete the entry is just a short workaround. The problem should be this one:  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/61950/magento-1-9-1-sending-multiple-emails